# Django middleware catches exception

Tags: python, django, exception, python-social-auth

I am using python-social-auth, and I am catching any exceptions using the following middleware:

```
class ExtendedSocialAuthExceptionMiddleware(SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if hasattr(social_exceptions, exception.__class__.__name__):
            return HttpResponse('error')
        else:
            raise exception
```

What I would like to do in this exception handler is redirect the user to the page they came from, and display the exception in a label in that template. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) :

`return redirect(url)`